# Require All Fields in Initializer List

Tags: c++, gcc

Suppose, I have a structure

```
struct A
{
  int a;
  int b;
};
```

I would like to forbid initialization it the following way:

```
A a = {1};
```

But the following should be OK:

```
A a = {1, 2};
```

I can add an explicit constructor. But such a solution requires adding the constructor to all the structures in the project that is not convenient.

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ does not have a reputation for being convenient. Having said that: If `b` never has to be changed after the struct is constructed, explicitly declaring it `const` will force it to be initialized explicitly.

Comment: Whatever solution prevails, it will involve changing all these structures anyway in one form or another, so I'm not entirely clear where your inconvenience would be saved regardless. Or is the purpose just to break the code when this happens?

Answer (score 2):

Both GCC and Clang support `-Werror=missing-field-initializers`, which turns this into an error.

`-Wmissing-field-initializers` (warning, not error) is a part of the `-Wextra`.

Comment: Downside: rejects incomplete initializations of ALL structures, not just the target, and that might be too-wide an umbrella.

Comment: @user4581301 He said `But such a solution requires adding the constructor to all the structures in the project that is not convenient` so he wants it for ALL structures.

Comment: @ssbssa A Stack Overflow answer is for the Asker and all future programmers with a similar problem, some of which will only want to protect one or a few structures. The comment gives those future askers a heads-up that they'll have to keep looking.